# Panel-specific annotations or similar mechanism for Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

Annotations are extremely useful, but lose a lot of their utility when you have panels with widely different time ranges. For example, we have a panel with an hour time range, and another panel that shows the last three months history. With the existing annotation mechanism we have to either decide between completely burrying the 3-M-Graph under annotations or have practically no annotations in the 1-H-Graph.

Ideas we have explored that did not work:

- SQL queries that generate annotations (for example a midnight marker) based on the time range supplied. It turns out that the annotation query is only ran once for the dashboard, not per panel
- Annotations with tags that could be enabled or disabled per panel. Also only works dashboard-level
- Annotations that are panel specific through the HTTP/REST-API. While generally a good concept, we need dynamic annotations generated from a source, not a push based system.

Does anyone have a solution we could try ? We aren't married to annotations, but we need visible markers to mark things such as midnight every day and error events (which we have as SQL TIMESTAMP information).

Comment: The per panel annotation is possible via the rest api, but your usecase seems like you can use the graph panel with point markers on top of the line.